# Angular 2 beta16 Cannot read property 'MinFreeShipping' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't "print" a variable in angular 2 beta 16. This is the call to the services. If i log "this.menu" it is correctly displayed, but it is not working in the template file, i get the error cannot read property MinFreeShipping of undefined.

```
export class MenuComponent {

menu: any;
title = 'asd'; 

constructor(private _restaurantService: RestaurantService) {
    _restaurantService.getMenu(localStorage.getItem('id_firm'))
        .map((res: Response) => { return res.json() })
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.menu = data;
            console.log(this.menu); // Object {Groups: Array[0],VariantGroups: Array[0], MinFreeShipping: 15, ShippingFee: 5}

        });
    }
}
```

The get menu function in restaurantService is:

```
getMenu(id: number): any {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('token', localStorage.getItem('auth_token'));

    var uri = this._baseUri + 'Menu' + '/' + id;
    return this.http.get(uri, new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }));            
}
```

The template is

```
{{title}} // print [object Object]
{{menu.MinFreeShipping }} // error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are trying to access it before you get the proper value.

When your template loads your menu variable is undefined and you are trying to access a property of an undefined object.

What you can do here is that you should define a default value for your menu property then it should work as expected.

```
menu: any = {Groups: [],VariantGroups: [], MinFreeShipping: 0, ShippingFee: 0}
```

This would mean, initially on your template you'll get a view with default value and when the answer of your request gets back it will be updated.

Or another way to do this without default values would be to use [*ngIf](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgIf-directive.html)

This way you can check if menu is not undefined and only then show that part of the template.

```
<div *ngIf="menu!==undefined">
  {{menu.MinFreeShipping }}
</div>
```

The proper way of doing it if you ask me would be to have a model like this:

```
export class MenuModel { 
  Groups: ProductGroupModel[]; 
  VariantGroups: VariantGroupModel[]; 
  MinFreeShipping: number; 
  ShippingFee: number; 

  constructor(obj?: any) {
    this.Groups= obj && obj.Groups || []; // This may also change based on the Groups model you have. You may initialize here also
    this.VariantGroups = obj && obj.VariantGroups || []; // This also
    this.MinFreeShipping= obj && obj.MinFreeShipping || 0;
    this.ShippingFee = obj && obj.ShippingFee || 0;
  }
}
```

This way you can use:

```
menu:MenuModel = new MenuModel();
```

And for when the request is returned:

```
this.menu = new MenuModel(data);
```

The advantage of this would be you would actually have a proper model. The problem when you get a response from the server that's not your model, just a data having the same fields. So if you write getters and setters for your model it won't work if you don't instantiate an object with the data from the server, just make it equal as you did.

Comment: something like public menu: MenuModel = new MenuModel() ; or menu: menu: any = {} ?

Comment: Well if you have a MenuModel then you should use it, but be sure to add default values for your properties in the constructor of the model.

Comment: my model is like this, i have to change the property name ( groups to Groups) ?
export class MenuModel {
    groups: ProductGroupModel[];
    variantGroups: VariantGroupModel[];
    minFreeShipping: number;
    shippingFee: number;
}

Comment: Well your model should be the same as your response. So if you return MinFreeShipping, use that in your model also, because it's case sensitive :)

Comment: I updated my answer to include a more proper way of doing what you want :) Hope it helps.